# Calling unexisting controller, how to generate exception?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I'm writing my own little MVC and I got a question... I'm passing `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` to the `Router` class which returns me controller, it's action and array of GET parameters.
(For example Router said that I should call `App_Controller->index()`).

So, I should create instance of `App_Controller` and call `index()` method. So, I'm doing something like `$controller = new $controller_name` etc. But what if controller is not found by `spl_autoload_register()` (I'm using autoload).

How can I generate Exception about the fact that controller is not found? Or maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check it using [`class_exists`](http://php.net/class_exists) which has a $autoload parameter (set to true as default, and therefore tries to autoload the class).

```
if(!class_exists($controller_name)) throw new Exception('Controller does not exist'); 
$controller = new $controller_name();
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much! Absolutely the same about checking if class method exists, right? (using `method_exists`)

Comment: @Kirzilla actually, yes, works the same way and considers autoloading. I used it myself in a similiar situation (and was actually surprised that it worked with autoloading ;)).